# Prevent mouse events during wpf Window.OnActivate

Tags: c#, wpf

Is it possible to prevent mouse events when a window is activated?

For example, I have a C# window and I change the focus to something else such as a browser. When I reactivate the c# window by clicking on it, I don't want any mouse events to be executed. The first click on the window should just activate it. Mouse Events are only fired if the window is already activated.

Answer (score 0):

An event will be fired then a user clicks on your wpf controll but why don't you just handle the event?

Subscribe to the event and prevent it to bubble up the visual tree:

```
private void Panel_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Have a look at this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/464926/To-bubble-or-tunnel-basic-WPF-events) it describes the event bubble and tunneling in WPF.

Comment: I don't want to prevent it at all times, I want to prevent it while the window is beeing activated by clicking on it. if it is already activated, mouse events should fire.
Unfortunately, by the time the handler is called, the window is already set to activated so I cant check the window state.

Comment: I'm not full aware of what your problem is but you could think about overriding the `Window.OnActivated` to handle if an event should be handled by you methods. [Link to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.onactivated.aspx)